# Trouble implementing logarithmic matrix norm

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I wanted to write a quick function that calculates the [logarithmic matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_norm) with respect to the spectral norm. The formula is

$$
\mu_2(A) = \lambda_\mathrm{max}\left(\frac{A + A^T}2\right).
$$

So I implemented it by

```
lognorm[A_] = First@Eigenvalues[(N[A] + Transpose[A])/2, 1];
```

Unfortunately, for `lognorm[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]` I get `{{1, 5/2}, {5/2, 4}}` as result. If I use

```
lognorm2[A_] = Eigenvalues[(N[A] + Transpose[A])/2, 1];
```

I get for `lognorm2[{{1,2},{3,4}}]` the result $\{\frac{1}{2} (5+\sqrt{34})\}$, which is strange because it is an exact result, although I added `N` in the definition of `lognorm` and `lognorm2`.

What is the reason for this and how can I write a `lognorm` function that works properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer: I have to use deferred definitions with `:=`. Otherwise Mathematica would calculate

```
First@Eigenvalues[(N[A] + Transpose[A])/2, 1]
```

which gives

```
1/2 (A+Transpose[A])
```

for some reason and then bind this to `lognorm`.

If I use `:=` instead, the right hand side is evaluated each time the function is actually called.

See the documentation:
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html

---

Also note that `Eigenvalues` sorts the Eigenvalues by their absolute value, which means that `Eigenvalues[{{1, 0}, {0, -5}},1]` gives`-5` instead of `1`, because $|-5|>|1|$. A correct implementation would be

```
lognorm[A_] := Max[Eigenvalues[(N[A]+Transpose[A])/2]];
```